# Simulate a double click on an html element

Tags: javascript, dom, simulation, mouse

Yo,

For the past weeks i try to simulate a double on my element but i can't find a solution. I know the `click()` method exist but i can't find a smilary method for my problem. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger `dblclick` event by using `dispatchEvent` like this:

```
const event = new MouseEvent('dblclick');
document.getElementById('myId').dispatchEvent(event);
```

If you are using `JQuery`, The second way is:

```
$('#myId').dblclick()
```

```js
var button = document.getElementById("myButton");
button.addEventListener("dblclick", function() {
  alert("Works!");
});

const event = new MouseEvent('dblclick');
button.dispatchEvent(event);
```

```html
<button id="myButton">Test</button>
```

Comment: @Ivar I just updated my answer, It just works when using `JQuery`

Comment: Thanks. Do note that questions like these are very likely to have already been answered on Stack Overflow and [we prefer to close them as duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates) instead of answering them.